# Google Sheets Query with Cell References Only Returning Headers

Tags: sql, google-sheets

`=query('Budget Data'!$A:$Y, "SELECT A,B, E, w Where  A = '"&K1&"'AND W = "&$D$1,-1)`

My Query Is looking to retrieve 4 columns from a larger dataset on "Budget Data" sheet dependent on brand name and reporting month date. I am referencing two cells for Brand Name (K1) and Date(D1). However, it is only returning the Header Row of Data. I have double checked data types and everything is matched correctly.

How can I get the rest of the data to show in this query?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are trying to date match b/w `D1` and `column W`, then try:

```
=query('Budget Data'!A:Y, "SELECT A,B,E,W Where  E = '"&K1&"' AND W=date '"&text(G1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")
```

if its to match month of the date in `D1` cell and relevant month data in `column W`, then use:

```
=query('Budget Data'!A:Y, "SELECT A,B,E,W Where  E = '"&K1&"' AND month(W)="&month(G1)-1)
```

Comment: The cell references in your comment were a bit off but I was able to make this query work thanks to your help: 

`=query('Budget Data'!A:Y, "SELECT A,B,E,W Where  A = '"&C1&"' AND month(W)="&month(D1)-1)`  

Thanks!